# ASP.NET WebAPI + Soap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Does WebAPI support SOAP? I'm trying to write a SOAP Server  in MVC4 and whilst I can do it in WCF it seems that WebAPI is replacing this but I see no ways to utilize SOAP in this yet, just JSON / XML using a REST Style interface.

Comment: If it's important to have both, you could always use the WCF REST 4.0 templates, and provide POX/JSON service endpoints, and also have custom SOAP endpoints mixed in there for your RPC.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote Scott Guthrie: The last few years have seen the rise of Web APIs - services exposed over plain HTTP rather than through a more formal service contract (like SOAP or WS*).

So I would say no.

Comment: bummer :( Whilst this is true, not everyone has moved to SOAP so interop still requires SOAP.

Comment: Using REST API doesn't mean you can't have a formal contract - like swagger for example.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar True enough, but if the formal contract doesn't bring any end user value I would not bother.

Answer (score 18):

You should consider looking at [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) which allows your same service to support REST + SOAP APIs, although since SOAP only works over [HTTP POST it has some restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support)

### [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference)

As an alternative to SOAP, ServiceStack offers a better alternative to WCF's **Add Service Reference** which can generate a typed API from a URL using [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference) feature that's built into [ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Creating-your-first-project).

### Advantages over WCF

- **Simple** Uses a small T4 template to save generated POCO Types. Updating as easy as re-running T4 template
- **Versatile** Clean DTOs works in all JSON, XML, JSV, MsgPack and ProtoBuf [generic service clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#built-in-clients)
- **Reusable** Generated DTO's are not coupled to any endpoint or format. Defaults are both partial and virtual for maximum re-use
- **Resilient** Messaging-based services offer a number of [advantages over RPC Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services)
- **Flexible** DTO generation is customizable, Server and Clients can override built-in defaults
- **Integrated** Rich Service metadata annotated on DTO's, [Internal Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) are excluded when accessed externally

### WebAPI and WCF both promote RPC method signatures

What's interesting is that despite [WebAPI ApiController methods](http://mono.servicestack.net/files/slide-34.png) having taken the same [RPC approach as WCF](http://mono.servicestack.net/files/slide-35.png) in using C# RPC methods to create and define chatty web services with, that they're still not able to support their own SOAP standard made by the same company.

#### ServiceStack supports REST, SOAP, HTML and MQ endpoints with same service

This is a testament to ServiceStack's [message-based design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/What-is-a-message-based-web-service%3F) which offers [numerous advantages](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services) not withstanding being able for the **same service** to support multiple endpoints and formats including REST, SOAP and MQ endpoints as well as [generating server-side or client-side HTML websites](http://razor.servicestack.net/) if you need it. Here's an example of a rich [Northwind database editor](http://northwind.mattjcowan.com/customers) that because it was built with ServiceStack automatically enables a typed REST APIs that is able to be called with rich native Desktop clients, Mobile Apps and Single Page Apps.

#### SOAP is still a poor option for remote services

Although despite supporting SOAP for interoperability, accessibility and backwards compatibility reasons, we don't recommend it for building web services platforms with as it's un-necessarily complex, brittle, slow and verbose and there are much better alternatives to use. I [explain more in detail in my interview on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack).

Comment: A problem with ServiceStack is that actions return type System.Object making compile-time type checking difficult.

Comment: @stimpy77 That's completely optional, you can specify a concrete return type whenever preferred. Note we prefer specifying the response type on the `IReturn<T>` marker so the client gets a typed API as well.

Comment: Did this "completely optional" behavior change in v4 or was it always optional?

Comment: @stimpy77 The [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) allows for it, not available in the original old API in v3 since it forced overriding existing methods.

Answer (score 16):

WEB API is Microsoft's answer to REST based apis. If you want SOAP, go with WCF.

Answer (score 7):

WebApi does not support SOAP out of the box, indeed. But it is a quite flexible framework and you could "adapt" it to handle SOAP: nothing prevents you from manually parsing the received SOAP messages (they are plain XML after all) and manually generating the responses as XML strings, then sending them with the approproate content-type header (you could even [write your own content formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) for this).

Depending on your needs and your existing codebase, this may be worth the effort or you may want to use a more SOAP-firendly technology such as WCF or the already mentioned [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) framework.

Comment: I did just this recently and created my own SoapMessageFormatter so that HTTP POSTS that had the application/soap+xml request format got piped into a special endpoint designed to parse the XML and translate it into a POCO so that it could be handled normally.  Then the result went through the same translation in response.

Comment: I wrote an answer on How to Receive SOAP request using ASP MVC here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985639/is-it-possible-to-model-bind-a-soap-request-with-mvc/58254951#58254951

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) which should support both SOAP and REST in one interface without any hassle.  It claims to be a [better match than WebAPI for web services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services).

I can't claim to know everything about the difference, but the problems they claim are inherent in the Web API approach I can say from experience *are* real - API evolution (inevitable in a real project) is quite tricky in web api.  And of course, web api doesn't support SOAP.

Answer (score 2):

It is not like Wed API supports SOAP but due to SOAP is just a standard that uses XML and it travels throw HTTP you can use Web API to expose a POST Service to read the XML and find the nodes you need using XPath and then Deserialize the nodes to objects.

First, you need to add XML support to the ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
    }
```

Then in your controller, you just need to add a method that receives an XMLDocument and with XPath search for the node you are interested (Basically removing the soap envelope, the header, the body) and then you can deserialize the object.
In my case, I add the service reference using the WSDL and with that, I deserialize the object.

```
[HttpPost("reservationxml")]
    public void CreateReservationFromTSW(XmlDocument soapCreateReservationRq)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(soapCreateReservationRq.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("r", "http://soa.company.com/ReservationEnt");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");

        XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = soapCreateReservationRq.SelectNodes("s:Envelope/s:Body/r:CreateReservationRq",nsmgr);
        XmlNode xmlnode = xmlNodeList[0];
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceReference1.CreateReservationRqType));
        ServiceReference1.CreateReservationRqType rq = (ServiceReference1.CreateReservationRqType)serial.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xmlnode));


    }
```

As you can see in the next image the service that tries to consume your service uses a Request Method POST with the Accept-Encoding: gzip. That is why you can expose a Web API that can be consumed for a SOAP service.
[image]