# Is it possible to model bind a soap request with mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A client has a service that sends out xml soap formatted requests that we need to receive via our .Net MVC4 project.  A request would be in the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ReceiveStatusUpdate xmlns="http://test.com">
            <StatusUpdate>
                <Reference>214563</Reference>
                <ThirdPartyReference>YOUR-REFERENCE</ThirdPartyReference>
                <Status>Pending</Status>
            </StatusUpdate>
        </ReceiveStatusUpdate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm wondering what would be the best way to receive and parse this request?

Comment: Out of interest is it necessary to handle this via MVC? What about a WCF or potentially even web api end point? See this thread for a discussion of web api + soap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317572/asp-net-webapi-soap

Comment: I'd either make a WebAPI and have the client talk to it via a RESTful interface, or make a WCF service instead of an MVC application if you must use SOAP. Out of the box there's no way MVC can handle SOAP messages, you should do that with custom code.

Comment: I'm in the same situation - the main application is built using of ASP MVC and we need to create an endpoint to support WCF SOAP POST request from our partner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use an old-fashioned asmx web service.

Exposing via Web API would require considerable work as it does not support SOAP binding out of the box.

You could use a WCF service, but they can be fiddly and time consuming to configure, which is the price to pay for their flexibility.

In short, if you only need to support SOAP bindings, use the tool that was made for that job - asmx web services.

Just add a new item to your MVC project of type Web Service (ASMX), example shown below (you'd obviously have your StatusUpdate class defined in a separate file).

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for StatusWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class StatusWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void ReceiveStatusUpdate(StatusUpdate StatusUpdate)
    {
        //Do whatever needs to be done with the status update
    }
}

public class StatusUpdate
{
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string ThirdPartyReference { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the bounty for this as you're correct in that this will work.  I however got it working through parsing the input stream from the Request my controller method, I'll leave a separate answer with my solution

Answer (score 1):

Slightly hacky way of doing this but it worked for me and it's a one off request type that I need to handle.  I basically pulled the request body out and parsed it with XDocument

```
public ActionResult Update()
{
    var inputStream = Request.InputStream;
    inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var request = new StreamReader(inputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var soapRequest = XDocument.Parse(request);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - maybe someone can say more about it, would be to choose WebAPI. It's simple to use, just some code so it's light. You have lot's of tools for processing XML documents in .NET so this wont be any problem for you.

There is one more thing. In your XML there is error, the closing tag "ReceiveStatusUpdate" is misspelled.

This will be helpful in the beginning: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api
Then you can use Fiddler to post those XML's to your WebAPI.

Comment: Thanks I've edited that, I've changed the actual xml tags for this question

Comment: Okay so whats more would you need?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best answer BUT here is what I'm doing now.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult HotelAvailRQ(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    // Parse the SOAP request to get the data payload
    var xmlPayload = MyHelper.GetSoapXmlBody(request);

    // Deserialize the data payload
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OpenTravel.Data.CustomAttributes.OTA_HotelAvailRQ));
    var hotelAvailRQ = (OpenTravel.Data.CustomAttributes.OTA_HotelAvailRQ)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlPayload));

    return Ok();
}
```

Helper class

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static string GetSoapXmlBody(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

        var xmlData = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
        var xmlBodyElement = xmlData.GetElementsByTagName("SOAP-ENV:Body");

        var xmlBodyNode = xmlBodyElement.Item(0);
        if (xmlBodyNode == null) throw new Exception("Function GetSoapXmlBody: Can't find SOAP-ENV:Body node");

        var xmlPayload = xmlBodyNode.FirstChild;
        if (xmlPayload == null) throw new Exception("Function GetSoapXmlBody: Can't find XML payload");

        return xmlPayload.OuterXml;
    }
}
```