# Return WCF SOAP Response from ASP Web API

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap

I have an ASP Web API project that needs to receive a WCF SOAP request and return the result in SOAP respond.

I'm planning not to create a WCF service because I need only ONE endpoint to work with this partner.

I manage to [receive and process the SOAP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985639/is-it-possible-to-model-bind-a-soap-request-with-mvc/58254951#58254951).

**My challenge now is to return my result / response in SOAP format, how do I do it?**

Comment: `asp` is not the correct tag to use here; you seem to have created it accidentally. I replaced this with [tag:asp.net] but please correct this to [tag:asp.net-core] if that’s what you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview)

> Services written with the WCF WEB HTTP programming model do not use
>   SOAP messages.