# .NET WS/SOAP capabilities

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am reading that WCF is becoming obsolete, but no mentioning about what should be used for SOAP protocols in these cases. Is WCF our only option in .NET? To my understanding WEB API does not support SOAP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET WebAPI + Soap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317572/asp-net-webapi-soap)

Comment: I love "technology *x* is becoming obsolete" statements without any cited references, blogs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I am reading that WCF is becoming obsolete

Really? Maybe someone should tell the thousands of public and private enterprises around the world which rely on it every day.

> Is WCF our only option (for SOAP) in .NET?

No. For example, [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) supports SOAP.

> To my understanding WEB API does not support SOAP

Your understanding is correct.